# Slow VBA macro reading/writing from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a macro that will evaluate the fields in columns O through V for 800 or so rows. I've read that reading and writing take the longest, which is what I am essentially doing.

Because there is a lot of data, it is running pretty slowly. It'll take a minute, maybe a little more, to run through everything, and it'll say that Excel isn't responding while it runs.

I need some help optimizing it because I'm not very familiar with VBA, but I've done everything I can think of to make faster. I've read that using 2 dimensional arrays would help, but I have no idea how that would work for this situation.

Any help or advice would be appreciated! Thank you for your time :-)

```
Sub Check_Missing()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim LastRow, LastRow2 As Long
Dim col
Dim i, j, 
Dim M, N, P As String
Dim summarySh, resultsSh As Worksheet

Set summarySh = Sheets("summary")
Set resultsSh = Sheets("Results")

col = Array("O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V")
M = "Missing"
N = "No"
P = "Partial"

LastRow = summarySh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastRow2 = resultsSh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

resultsSh.Range("A2:AC" & LastRow2).Clear

For i = 2 To LastRow
    For j = LBound(col) To UBound(col)
        If summarySh.Cells(i, col(j)).Value = M Or summarySh.Cells(i,             
col(j)).Value = N Or summarySh.Cells(i, col(j)).Value = P Then
            summarySh.Cells(i, col(j)).EntireRow.Copy     
Destination:=resultsSh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

            GoTo ContinueForLoop

        End If

    Next j
ContinueForLoop:
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This is a side question, so if you happen to know, that would be great, but if not I'm sure I can figure it out.

I have to compare two workbooks (one is the one I'm working with and the other is downloaded externally), and I was hoping to call Inquire, an Excel Add-in function, so that it would pop up immediately if someone else were to use my macro, since it'll be just a bit more user=friendly.

Comment: When you are declaring variables in the same line you need to do it like so: `Dim LastRow As Long, LastRow2 As Long`, otherwise only the last variable in that line is declared as the type you want it to be and the others are of type `Variant`. This could potentially affect the speed of execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub Check_Missing()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
    Dim wsResults As Worksheet
    Dim rFind As Range
    Dim rCopy As Range
    Dim aFindPhrases As Variant
    Dim vPhrase As Variant
    Dim sCheckCols As String
    Dim sFirst As String

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsSummary = wb.Worksheets("summary")
    Set wsResults = wb.Worksheets("Results")

    sCheckCols = "O:V"  'If getting non-continuous columns, can use this style (for example): "O:O,Q:S,U:V"
    aFindPhrases = Array("Missing", "No", "Partial")

    For Each vPhrase In aFindPhrases
        Set rFind = wsSummary.Range(sCheckCols).Find(vPhrase, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            sFirst = rFind.Address
            Do
                Select Case (rCopy Is Nothing)
                    Case True:  Set rCopy = rFind.EntireRow
                    Case Else:  Set rCopy = Union(rCopy, rFind.EntireRow)
                End Select
                Set rFind = wsSummary.Range(sCheckCols).FindNext(rFind)
            Loop While rFind.Address <> sFirst
        End If
    Next vPhrase

    wsResults.UsedRange.Offset(1).ClearContents
    If Not rCopy Is Nothing Then rCopy.Copy wsResults.Cells(wsResults.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Why "give this a try"? How does it answer the question - what are the learning values (SO long-term information) from what you have suggested?

Comment: I changed ClearContents to just Clear since it was giving me an error and it ran so fast! It was able to go through all the data in just a few seconds, which made me very happy. Thanks for taking the time to write out the solution for me. I'm very new to VBA so I just need to take the time to understand everything you did lol

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, when you declare multiple variables in the same line of code, you have to do it like so:

```
Dim LastRow As Long, LastRow2 As Long
Dim M As String, N As String, P As String
Dim summarySh As Worksheet, resultsSh As Worksheet
```

Otherwise only the last variable in that line is declared as the type you want it to be and the others are of type `Variant`. This could potentially affect the speed of execution. Especially when you have to do with `Long` type.

`i` and `j` need to be declared as `Long` as well.

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long
```

`col` should be declared as a variant:

```
Dim col() As Variant
```

Please avoid using the `GoTo` statement. It's an outdated and bad practice which makes the code hard to read and maintain and could lead to confusion and unwanted behavior.

You should use a `Do-While` loop instead of a `For-Next` combined with `GoTo`. If I understand your logic correctly, you could do something like the following:

```
For i = 2 To LastRow
    j = 0
    Do While j <= UBound(col) And Not (summarySh.Cells(i, col(j)).Value = M Or summarySh.Cells(i, col(j)).Value = n Or summarySh.Cells(i, col(j)).Value = P)
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    If j < UBound(col) + 1 Then
        summarySh.Cells(i, col(j)).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=resultsSh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for taking a look. I did read about how bad GoTo statements were, but my original for loop was repeating values because I wasn't exiting at the appropriate moment and GoTo was the easiest solution. Since this script is pretty simple, I figured it'd be ok. You got my logic spot on by the way! It sped up my solution a bit, but it's still freezing the excel application. Thanks again for your help